# powershell multiple block expressions

Tags: powershell

I am replacing multiple strings in a file.  The following works, but is it the best way to do it?  I'm not sure if doing multiple block expressions is a good way.

```
(Get-Content $tmpFile1) |
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'replaceMe1.*', 'replacedString1'} |
             % {$_ -replace 'replaceMe2.*', 'replacedString2'} |
             % {$_ -replace 'replaceMe3.*', 'replacedString3'} |
Out-File $tmpFile2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to foreach through each replace operations.  Those operators can be chained in a single command:

```
@(Get-Content $tmpFile1) -replace 'replaceMe1.*', 'replacedString1' -replace 'replaceMe2.*', 'replacedString2' -replace 'replaceMe3.*', 'replacedString3' |
Out-File $tmpFile2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your patterns and replacements don't really just have a digit on the end that is different, so you might want to execute different code based on which regex actually matched.
If so you can consider using a single regular expression but using a function instead of a replacement string. The only catch is you have to use the regex `Replace` method instead of the operator.

```
PS C:\temp> set-content -value @"
replaceMe1 something
replaceMe2 something else
replaceMe3 and another
"@  -path t.txt

PS C:\temp> Get-Content t.txt |
ForEach-Object { ([regex]'replaceMe([1-3])(.*)').Replace($_,
   { Param($m)
     $head = switch($m.Groups[1]) { 1 {"First"}; 2 {"Second"}; 3 {"Third"} }
     $tail = $m.Groups[2]
     "Head: $head, Tail: $tail"
   })}
Head: First, Tail:  something
Head: Second, Tail:  something else
Head: Third, Tail:  and another
```

This may be overly complex for what you need today, but it is worth remembering you have the option to use a function.

Answer (score 0):

The [`-replace` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847759.aspx) uses regular expressions, so you can merge your three script blocks into one like this:

```
Get-Content $tmpFile1 `
    | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'replaceMe([1-3]).*', 'replacedString$1' } `
    | Out-File $tmpFile2
```

That will search for the literal text `'replaceMe'` followed by a `'1'`, `'2'`, or `'3'` and replace it with `'replacedString'` followed by whichever digit was found (the `'$1'`).

Also, note that `-replace` works like `-match`, not `-like`; that is, it works with regular expressions, not wildcards.  When you use `'replaceMe1.*'` it doesn't mean "the text `'replaceMe1.'` followed by zero or more characters" but rather "the text `'replaceMe1'` followed by zero or more occurrences (`'*'`) of *any* character (`'.'`)".  The following demonstrates text that will be replaced even though it wouldn't match with wildcards:

```
PS> 'replaceMe1_some_extra_text_with_no_period' -replace 'replaceMe1.*', 'replacedString1'
replacedString1
```

The wildcard pattern `'replaceMe1.*'` would be written in regular expressions as `'replaceMe1\..*'`, which you'll see produces the expected result (no replacement performed):

```
PS> 'replaceMe1_some_extra_text_with_no_period' -replace 'replaceMe1\..*', 'replacedString1'
replaceMe1_some_extra_text_with_no_period
```

You can read more about regular expressions in the .NET Framework [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hs600312.aspx).